# Using HTML to play a GIF

Tags: android, html, animation, button, gif

I'm constructing a little web-app in HTML5, but I can't employ Javascript as the app will be used on mobile. (as far as I know Javascript isn't enabled by default on most phones?)

I want a still image to be shown by default, but when a button is pressed the image will animate as a GIF and then produce a few alerts once the animation is finished.

How can I switch a JPG to a GIF on the press of a button below the animation?
How can I produce an alert on the completion of the GIF?

Thanks!

Comment: You'd still need to use javascript for that.  But why do you think that JS is disabled?

Comment: Really? I had read somewhere that it was disabled on most phones by default. Would Javascript work on iPhone and Android?

Comment: @bloodprime - no reason to think it would be disabled. In order for Flash to be superseded, something had to replace it. That something is the HTML5 canvas and javascript. HTML5 canvas animations work just fine on my android 2.3 phone. (I'd be stunned if any general-purpose phones come with JS disabled. Security-conscious solutions like the BlackPhone may vary)

Comment: Great! Thanks a bunch, I'll look for a javascript solution.